# Issue saving strokeStyle

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm having a bad time trying to understand why the style stack on canvas doesn't work when using strokStyle.
So far, I got this.

```
ctx_graph.strokeStyle = "blue";
ctx_graph.moveTo(100,100);
ctx_graph.lineTo(150,150);
ctx_graph.stroke();
ctx_graph.save();

ctx_graph.moveTo(200,100);
ctx_graph.lineTo(300,300);
ctx_graph.stroke();

ctx_graph.strokeStyle = "red";
ctx_graph.moveTo(250,100);
ctx_graph.lineTo(350,350);
ctx_graph.stroke();
ctx_graph.save();
```

So my output should be two blue lines and one red line, but for some weird reason I got two violet lines and one red line. I can't figure it out why this happened.

Comment: remember to use beginPath.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because it's setting the `strokeColor` for the entire path so far each time it's changed. So the items between `"blue"` and `"red"` will have both colors applied, getting your purple color. To separate the paths enclose your lines in by calling `beginPath` (*this will start a new path*), otherwise it will simply merge your two colors set in `strokeColor`:

```js
var ctx_graph = document.getElementById("canvas").getContext("2d");

ctx_graph.beginPath();
    ctx_graph.strokeStyle = "blue";
    ctx_graph.moveTo(100,100);
    ctx_graph.lineTo(150,150);
    ctx_graph.stroke();
    ctx_graph.save();

    ctx_graph.moveTo(200,100);
    ctx_graph.lineTo(300,300);
    ctx_graph.stroke();

// Calling beginPath here will close the last path, so the items above will not have both
// colors.
ctx_graph.beginPath();
    ctx_graph.strokeStyle = "red";
    ctx_graph.moveTo(250,100);
    ctx_graph.lineTo(350,350);
    ctx_graph.stroke();
    ctx_graph.save();
```

```html
<canvas id="canvas" width=400 height=400 />
```

Comment: @user2958452 Great, since this answered your question I would appreciate you marking it as accepted, that way others know it's answered.

Comment: @GameAlchemist Ah, yeah it should be called before `.stroke()`, in this case calling `.beginPath()` will start a new path for the next shape. I mostly used it to show what's happening (even though it doesn't really do anything). But yeah it can be excluded. I'll edit my answer, I'm just used to using it since I close shapes often.